# c# defined variables in a method as a list - is it possible?

Tags: c#

In php, you can get the method's defined variables as an array:

```
function test($a,$b){
  print_r(
       get_defined_vars()
  );
}
```

Is it possible in C#?

Comment: [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) returns all variables in the current scope, including arguments and global variables. Thankfully, C# has nothing similar. In fact, a "scope" isn't really something that exists in run time in the same way it does in compile time, or in PHP. What exactly are you trying to do? There is probably a good way to do it...

Comment: @Kobi -  I have WebService Methods with a lot of parameters, I want to transffer it as a list and validate them outside if the webservice. I dont want to redeclare them again and again. Toda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection for this.

If you want to do this inline, then you first need to determine the method you are currently in.

```
var currentMethod = System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
```

Then you can retrieve the parameters of that method:

```
foreach(ParameterInfo parameter in currentMethod.GetParameters())
{
    var name = parameter.Name;
    //...
}
```

Comment: get_defined_vars() includes method parameters but is not limited to that.

Comment: Idd, it gets the variables within the scope that it is called (http://be2.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php). Looking at the OP's question getting the parameters of the current method should suffice for him.

Answer (score 3):

Something like...

```
string a = "hello";
int b = 20;
DateTime c = DateTime.Now;

foreach (LocalVariableInfo variable in MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().GetMethodBody().LocalVariables)
{
    Console.WriteLine(variable);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't even include the variables' names and values, as far as I can tell, and refers to the compiled code, which may have extra variables (like the IEnumerator, and the variable collection for example)

Comment: +1; Might want to append the method parameters to this, [ala Christophe's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495903/c-defined-variables-in-a-method-as-a-list-is-it-possible/7495977#7495977).